# Работа с изображениями

Tags: изображения, php

Здравствуйте!

У меня не работает вот этот код, который должен выводить PNG-изображение в окно браузера:

```
imagefill($image, 0, 0, 0x000080);
imageellipse($image, 40, 30, 50, 50, 0xFFFF00);
imagefilledellipse($image, 30, 20, 10, 10, 0xFFFF00);
imagefilledellipse($image, 50, 20, 10, 10, 0xFFFF00);
imageline($image, 40, 28, 40, 38, 0xFFFF00);
imagearc($image, 40, 30, 40, 40, 45, 135, 0xFFFF00);

header('Content-type: image/png'); 
imagepng($image);

imagedestroy($image);
```

В результате в браузер выдается изображение, которое выдается, если попытаться вывести несуществующее изображение... Хотя модуль для работы с изображениями есть, проверил через **phpinfo()**. В чем может быть проблема, друзья?

Comment: Ну что, никто не умеет работать с изображениями в PHP ? =)

Comment: Попробуйте создавать изображение через imagecreatetruecolor(), а не imagecreate().

Answer (score 1):

*Ну что, никто не умеет работать с изображениями в PHP ? =)*

[[@Asen](/users/5040/asen)](/users/5040/asen), умеет, как ни странно... >( Вот только под вечер телепатировать нет сил. Проверил ваш код и всё работает. [Вот что получается](http://test.webkey.net.ua/test.php), но почему у вас не пашет - не знаю.

```
// единствееное что добавил для проверки
$image = imagecreatetruecolor(100, 100);
// это ваше
imagefill($image, 0, 0, 0x000080);
imageellipse($image, 40, 30, 50, 50, 0xFFFF00);
imagefilledellipse($image, 30, 20, 10, 10, 0xFFFF00);
imagefilledellipse($image, 50, 20, 10, 10, 0xFFFF00);
imageline($image, 40, 28, 40, 38, 0xFFFF00);
imagearc($image, 40, 30, 40, 40, 45, 135, 0xFFFF00);

header('Content-type: image/png'); 
imagepng($image);

imagedestroy($image);
```

Comment: Спасибо...но вот почему код не работает у меня - не знаю. Выводится пустой поток изображения, то есть его как бы нет....ведь в PHP для этого должна быть подключена библиотека "GD" ?

---
P.S

Функции "imagecreatetruecolor(100, 100)", "imagecreate(100, 100)" использовались и в моем коде, но безрезультатно.